# Best way to migrate a question?

Tags: support, questions, migration

I asked this question a couple of weeks ago: [Defining the normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233471/defining-the-normal-distribution)

It hasn't received much attention and I've just become aware that there's a 'Math Educators' Beta SE where it would probably be better placed, but I don't have the rep to `vote-to-migrate`. Should I close it and repost it there, or can I request/volunteer for migration somehow?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest first consulting [What should I do if nobody answers my question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) in the help pages.

Failing that, simply flag your post for moderator attention.  Explain you would like it migrated (and suggest the destination).